# Isn't x/E = y/ E ⇔ x E y deduced, not just x/E = y/ E ⇒ x E y from (a) x/ E≠ Ø, (b) x/E ∩ y/ E ≠ Ø ⇔xEy?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

> "**Theorem 3.** Let $\mathscr E$ be an equivalence relation on a nonempty set $X$. Then
> (a) Each $x/\mathscr E$ is a nonempty subset of $X$.
> (b)  $x/\mathscr E \cap y/\mathscr E \neq \emptyset$ if and only if $x\mathscr Ey$.
> (c) $x\mathscr Ey$ if and only if $x/\mathscr E = y/\mathscr E$"

In the following proof of (c) I don't think it have to be as lengthy as like that

"Proof of Theorem 3

> (c) It follows immediately from (a) and (b) above that x/$\mathscr E$ = y/$\mathscr E \Rightarrow x \mathscr E$ y
>
> We need to prove that x$\mathscr E$y  $\Rightarrow x/\mathscr E = y/\mathscr E$
>
> Let x$\mathscr E$y. Then
> $z\in x/\mathscr E \Rightarrow z\mathscr E x$   Def. 6
> $z\mathscr Ex$ $\land$ $x\mathscr E y$ $\Rightarrow$ $z\mathscr Ey$ $\space\space\space\space\space\mathscr E$ is transitive.
> $\Rightarrow z\in y/\mathscr E$  Def. 6
> Since $z$ is arbitrary, it follows that $x/\mathscr E \subseteq y/\mathscr E$. A similar argument gives $y/\mathscr E \subseteq x/\mathscr E$; hence $x/\mathscr E \subset x/\mathscr E$
> "
> Source: Set Theory by You-Feng Lin, Shwu-Yeng T.Lin

The proof of Theorem 3 (c) can be shortened to the following:

$x/\mathscr E = y/\mathscr E$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x/\mathscr E \cap y/\mathscr E = x/\mathscr E \neq \emptyset$ by Idemp, (a)
$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\Leftrightarrow$ $x\mathscr E y$ by (b)

So there's no need to prove that $x\mathscr E y$  $\Rightarrow$ $x/\mathscr E = y/\mathscr E$, isn't it?

FYI

> **Idempotency law** of set (Idemp.): P$\bigcap P\Leftrightarrow P$, P$\bigcup P\Leftrightarrow P$
>
> **Definition** of equivalence class of $x$ in $X$ in symbols,
> $x/\mathscr E=\{y∈X| y \mathscr E x\} = \{y\in X | (y, x) \in\mathscr E\}$

"

> Definition 6. Let $\mathscr E$ be an equivalence relation on a nonempty set X . For each $x\in X$, we define
>
> X/​$\mathscr E$={y∈X∣y$\mathscr E$x}
>
> which is called the equivalence class determined by the element x.
>
> The set of all such equivalence classes on X is denoted by X/$\mathscr E$; that is, X/$\mathscr E$={x/$\mathscr E$∣x∈X} X/ɛ={x/$\mathscr E$∣$x\in X$}.
>
> The symbol X/ɛ is read "X modulo $\mathscr E$," or simply "X mod $\mathscr E$".

Comment: Related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238940/understanding-equivalence-class-equivalence-relation-partition

Comment: I think that [Michael Hardy's comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608135/where-in-a-and-b-above-shows-that-x-mathscr-e-y-mathscr-e-rightarrow-x?rq=1#comment3277568_1608135) on your previous post applies to the formatting of this post, too.

Comment: The right-to-left implications in your attempt at a shorter proof of (c) reads $x E y\to x/E\cap  y/E=x/E\ne \phi \to x/E=y/E.$  PROBLEMS:  From (a) and (b) you have $x E y \to x/E\cap y/E \ne \phi,$  but how does  $x/E \cap y/E \ne  \phi$  imply  that  $x/E\cap y/E=x/E$ unless you already know what you are trying to prove (which is $xEy \to x/E=y/E $ )?

Comment: @user254665 Aha. The right to left implication, doesn't suppose x/E=y/E, right? That cleared up my problem! Now I understand the proof

Comment: Exactly. You will find that partitions and equivalence relations are a widely used, very useful tool in many subjects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Comment*

From **Def. 6** we have that: if $x \mathrel{\mathscr{E}}y$, then $x \in y/\mathscr E$.

From **Th. 3(a)** we have that: $x \in x/\mathscr{E}$

Thus, we have that:

> if $x \mathrel{\mathscr{E}}y$, then $x \in x/\mathscr{E}\cap y/\mathscr{E} \neq \emptyset$.

Thus, how to conclude from: $x/\mathscr{E}\cap y/\mathscr{E}\neq \emptyset$ that $x/\mathscr{E} = y/\mathscr{E}$ ?

Consider the sets $A = \{ c \}$ and $B = \{ b, c \}$; we have two non-empty sets whose intersection is: $A \cap B = \{ c \} = A \ne \emptyset$.

But $A \ne B$.

---

Please, note that your version of "Idempotency" is wrong; we have:

> $P \cap P = P$;

it is *equality* between sets, and not *equivalence* between sentences regarding sets.

Comment: Did you check the Theorem (3) and my reason? $$"x/E = y/E ⇔ [x/E⋂ y/E = x/E] ≠∅   ⇔ xEb"$$

Comment: = is a equality relation, but in the set theory book, "P∩P=P" is called idempotency law.

Comment: @buzzee - but from **Theorem 4** [page 42] (b) The idempotency laws: $A U A = A$ and $A ∩ A = A$, it does not follows that : "if  $A ∩ B = A$, then $A=B$.

Comment: Aha, come to think of it. The author sometimes used ⇔ where = is normally used, so "x/E∩y/E=x/E≠∅" in my reasoning can be (x/E∩y/E)⇔(x/E≠∅), so the iff between them is wrong. (x/E∩y/E)⇒(x/E≠∅)

Comment: Oh, no, considering your sign again, mine should've been (x/E=y/E) ⇔ (x/E∩y/E=x/E)⇒(x/E∩y/E=≠∅), but I had thought (x/E=y/E) ⇔ (x/E∩y/E=x/E) ⇔(x/E∩y/E=≠∅).